How do I split a string with inconsistent data?
I have some imperial distances (miles/furlongs/yards) in a column which I am looking to convert into just furlongs. However, the data is inconsistent. Sometimes there is a furlongs value, sometimes there isn't. Sometimes yards is 'yds', sometimes it's just 'y'. A subset of the data is as follows:

1m
6f
1m 2f 0y (this is the most common format)
1m 30yds
2m 0f 32y
2m 2f

I'm very much a SQL beginner and haven't really dabbled in regex up to this point, but I thought something like this would do the job:
    SELECT 
    (NVL(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name, '[^m]+', 1, 1)),0) * 8) 
    + (NVL(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name, '[^f]+', 4, 1)),0) 
    + (NVL((CASE WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR (column_name,'\ ([^y]+)',5,1,NULL,1) < 55 THEN 0 WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR (column_name,'\ ([^y]+)',5,1,NULL,1) < 165 THEN 0.5 ELSE 1 END),0))) AS FURLONGS
    FROM table_name

However, this is failing because of the inconsistent formatting (I think).
Any help would be much appreciated.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

You could create your own formating on the data and then get the values for mile/yard/furlong so you could do the conversion,
the formating I did is:
Replace(' ' || Lower(DATA_VAL) || ' ', ' ', '/')
-- this transforms '2m 0f 32y' into '/2m/0f/32y/'

Sample data and the code bellow ...
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl ( ID, DATA_VAL ) AS
      ( Select 1, '1m'        From Dual Union All 
        Select 2, '6f'        From Dual Union All 
        Select 3, '1m 2f 0y'  From Dual Union All
        Select 4, '1m 30yds'  From Dual Union All
        Select 5, '2m 0f 32y' From Dual Union All
        Select 6, '2m 2f'     From Dual 
      ), 

... conversion values in a cte
    convs AS
      ( Select 1 "FURLONG", 8 "MILE", 0.0045454545 "YARD" From Dual),

... preparing the data  for conversion (cte grid)
    grid AS
      ( Select  ID, DATA_VAL,  
                To_Number(  Case When MILE_STR = '0' Then MILE_STR
                            Else SubStr( MILE_STR, Length(MILE_STR) - InStr(REVERSE( MILE_STR ), '/') + 2  ) 
                            End ) "MILE",
                --
                To_Number(  Case When YARD_STR = '0' Then YARD_STR
                            Else SubStr( YARD_STR, Length(YARD_STR) - InStr(REVERSE( YARD_STR ), '/') + 2  ) 
                            End  )"YARD",
                --
                To_Number(  Case When FURLONG_STR = '0' Then FURLONG_STR
                            Else SubStr( FURLONG_STR, Length(FURLONG_STR) - InStr(REVERSE( FURLONG_STR ), '/') + 2  ) 
                            End ) "FURLONG"
        From    ( Select ID, DATA_VAL,    -- Replace(' ' || Lower(DATA_VAL) || ' ', ' ', '/') ---> DATA_VAL_DELIMITEED,
                         --
                         Nvl(SubStr(Replace(' ' || Lower(DATA_VAL) || ' ', ' ', '/'), 1, InStr(Replace(' ' || Lower(DATA_VAL) || ' ', ' ', '/'), 'm', 1, 1) - 1 ), 0) "MILE_STR", 
                         Nvl(SubStr(Replace(' ' || Lower(DATA_VAL) || ' ', ' ', '/'), 1, InStr(Replace(' ' || Lower(DATA_VAL) || ' ', ' ', '/'), 'y', 1, 1) - 1 ), 0) "YARD_STR", 
                         Nvl(SubStr(Replace(' ' || Lower(DATA_VAL) || ' ', ' ', '/'), 1, InStr(Replace(' ' || Lower(DATA_VAL) || ' ', ' ', '/'), 'f', 1, 1) - 1 ), 0) "FURLONG_STR"
                  From   tbl
                )
      )

--      M a i n    S Q L : 
Select    g.ID, g.DATA_VAL, g.MILE, g.YARD, g.FURLONG, 
          ( g.MILE * c.MILE ) + ( g.YARD * c.YARD ) + ( g.FURLONG * c.FURLONG ) "TOTAL_FURLONGS"
From      grid g
Inner Join convs c ON( 1 = 1 )

/*     R e s u l t : 
        ID DATA_VAL        MILE       YARD    FURLONG TOTAL_FURLONGS
---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
         1 1m                 1          0          0              8
         2 6f                 0          0          6              6
         3 1m 2f 0y           1          0          2             10
         4 1m 30yds           1         30          0     8.13636364
         5 2m 0f 32y          2         32          0     16.1454545
         6 2m 2f              2          0          2             18   */

NOTE:
This works with the data provided but it is very dependable on your actual data. This will fail if there is maybe a space character between the number and m/y/f. If there actualy is - then (let's say, space and m) ' m' should be replaced with 'm' (m without space) first. We don't know your data - you do - so you should adjust this code to meet your actual context. This is just a basic approach to help you find your own solution.

You can do it with regexp, and recursive CTE to split the string:
select id, sum(
    case when instr(sub,'m') > 0 then 8*to_number(regexp_substr(sub, '\d+')) else 0 end +
    case when instr(sub,'f') > 0 then 1*to_number(regexp_substr(sub, '\d+')) else 0 end +
    case when instr(sub,'y') > 0 then 0.0045454545*to_number(regexp_substr(sub, '\d+')) else 0 end
    ) as total_furlongs
from (
    select id, level, data_val,
        regexp_substr(trim(lower(data_val)),'((\d+)([m|f|y(ds)*])\s*)+',1,level) as sub
    from tbl
    connect by 
        prior id = id and level <= regexp_count(trim(data_val),'((\d+)([m|f|y(ds)*])\s*)+', 1)
        and prior sys_guid() is not null
)
group by id
;

You may still have to improve the regexp on your actual data, but you have a starting point.
